# Web Audio API parameter modulation not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to modulate a filter with the output of another node, and having trouble getting this to work in Safari (6.0.4).

Here's a simplified code snippet:

```
context = new webkitAudioContext();

osc1 = context.createOscillator();

osc2 = context.createOscillator();
osc2.frequency.value = 2;
osc2.noteOn(0);

filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter.frequency.value = 100;

amp = context.createGainNode();
amp.gain.value = 100;

osc2.connect(amp);
amp.connect(filter.frequency);

osc1.connect(filter);
filter.connect(context.destination);

osc1.noteOn(0);
osc1.noteOff(2);
```

I've set up an example on jsFiddle with the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/p7EC6/

This works exactly as I want in Chrome - you can hear the filter frequency pulsing. In Safari, nothing happens. Interestingly, if I connect the amp output to a paramater of osc1 like `amp.connect(osc1.detune)`, it does work in Safari.

Is there a fundamental browser support issue here, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this was a bug that has since been fixed, but just not propagated into Safari's Webkit yet.  (I believe it would work on nightly builds.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. It was driving me crazy!